# Can not install Visual Studio 2022 Professional - Error Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.8.KB5003306

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have been struggeling to install VS 2022 Professional edition for a while now. At some point during the intallation i get the following error:

[image]

The logs show that there is a problem when executing dism.exe:
[image]

The DISM logs show that there is a problem loading image session:

[image]

I checked out this post https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/couldnt-install-microsoftnet48kb5003306-1/1578937
but no success. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Also tried this : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/packageidmicrosoftnet48kb5003306packageactioninsta-46/1589452, but when executing DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth i get "An error occurred while attempting to start the servicing process for the image located at C:.".
The log still show this error:

> DismHostLib: Failed to create dismhost.exe servicing process.

Comment: On the link it says "It seems that you have a **corrupted** file in your package cache.". You could try to uninstall everything that has to do with ".NET Framework 4.8", **reboot** your computer. After this try to (re-)install VS2022 (one of the option when re-installing this is to install the Framework again)

Comment: Hmm there is no .NET Framework 4.8 installed in my pc

Comment: Also not as part of your VS2019 install ? see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soJ5i.png

Comment: Yes, when i reinstalled vs2019 i see these packages for .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: From the [visual Studio 2022 System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/system-requirements): ".NET Framework 4.5.2 or above is required to install Visual Studio. Visual Studio requires .NET Framework 4.8 to run. If .NET Framework 4.8 isn't already installed, it will be installed during setup."

Comment: Microsoft also released a [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)  

Comment: Nothing worked, seems that in my pc KB5003306 could not be installed. This update can be installed also from Windows updates but i am using the company laptop and i do not have privileges to do that. Anyways, lets see. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use windows update in order to install previous security update for .NET Framework 4.8 after install reboot your computer and try again install VS2022

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when installing visual studio community 2022. Then I installed the same package by downloading visual studio community 2019 and it worked.